# Split A string on a term AND THEN splitting on another term

Tags: javascript

I have a poorly designed URL query string that I can't easily change e.g.

> [https://mysite/.shtml?source=999&promotype=promo&cmpid=abc-*-dfg-*-hif-_-1234&cm=qrs-stv-_wyx&aff=45628_THIS+IS+Test_Example](https://mysite/.shtml?source=999&promotype=promo&cmpid=abc-_-dfg-_-hif-_-1234&cm=qrs-stv-_wyx&aff=45628_THIS+IS+Test_Example)

I need to extract elements from it e.g. 45628

At the moment I'm using

```
document.URL.split(/aff=|_/)[5];
```

But I don't like this solution because if other parts of the URL structure change which is highly likely then my solution will break

Instead what I want to say is

> split on "aff=" AND THEN split on "_"

Is there an easy way to do this, looking for a JS answer

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you can do it like this:

```
document.URL.split("aff=")[1].split("_")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by splitting the string into tokens, if you can. Rather than working with `foo=bar&fin=bin`, break it down into `[['foo', 'bar'], ['fin', 'bin]]`. You can do that by splitting on the `&` and then the splitting each of those on the `=` character:

```js
const data = 'source=999&promotype=promo&cmpid=abc--dfg--hif-_-1234&cm=qrs-stv-_wyx&aff=45628_THIS+IS+Test_Example';

console.log(data.split('&').map(it => it.split('=')));
```

Next, take the tokens you want and extract the leading digits:

```js
const data = 'source=999&promotype=promo&cmpid=abc--dfg--hif-_-1234&cm=qrs-stv-_wyx&aff=45628_THIS+IS+Test_Example';

const tokens = data.split('&').map(it => it.split('='));
const [key,val] = tokens.find(([key]) => key === 'aff');
console.log(key, val.match(/[0-9]+/));
```

Answer (score 0):

var url = 'https://mysite/.shtml?source=999&promotype=promo&cmpid=abc--dfg--hif-_-1234&cm=qrs-stv-_wyx&aff=45628_THIS+IS+Test_Example';

var re = new RegExp(/aff=(\d+)/);
var ext = re.exec(url)[1];
alert(ext)